# Reason for endothermic nature of NaHCO3 + C2H4O2 reaction

Tags: acid-base, home-experiment

Why is the classic baking soda and vinegar reaction endothermic? Here are some possible answers I've come up with:

1. The dissolution of the sodium acetate absorbs energy,
2. The release of the carbon dioxide from solution absorbs energy, or
3. Some combination of the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "all of the above" answer is correct, with emphasis on number 2.  The phase change from a condensed phase (solid or liquid) to gas is almost always endothermic.  It's the same thing as wetting your hand then blowing on it.  The liquid water undergoes and endothermic phase transition which takes in heat from its surroundings, i.e. it evaporates and your hand gets cold.